# Angular js: Creating Boostrap modal Windows template: Trouble to define action for ng-click in button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a template for modal windows in my app. 
My goal is to set different parameters that will be applied to the modal Windows by using an dedicated object:

```
$scope.modalWarning = {
    Titre: "", 
    Texte: "", 
    Type: "", 
    Bouton1Valid: true, 
    Bouton1Libelle: "", 
    Bouton1Action: "", 
    Bouton2Valid: false, 
    Bouton2Libelle: "", 
    Bouton2Action: "" 
}
```

My template :

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="modalWarning" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="panel panel-{{modalWarning.Type}}">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2>{{modalWarning.Titre}}</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{modalWarning.Texte}}
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <button ng-show="modalWarning.Bouton1Valid" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="{{modalWarning.Bouton1Action}}">{{modalWarning.Bouton1Libelle}}</button>
                    <button ng-show="modalWarning.Bouton2Valid" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="{{modalWarning.Bouton2Action}}">{{modalWarning.Bouton2Libelle}}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my Angulars controller I have this initialization:

```
$scope.modalWarning.Titre = "Cloture de Mise a Jour : "
$scope.modalWarning.Texte = "Attention, après cette action, cette mise à jour ne sera plus accessible"
$scope.modalWarning.Type = "danger";
$scope.modalWarning.Bouton1Valid = true;
$scope.modalWarning.Bouton1Libelle = "Annuler";
$scope.modalWarning.Bouton2Valid = true;
$scope.modalWarning.Bouton2Libelle = "Continuer";
$scope.modalWarning.Bouton2Action = "CloseCurrentMAJOK()";

('#modalWarning').modal('show'); // to show modal windows
```

All settings work well, except action for button with ng-click.
Parameter for action in ng-click directive is defined by:  modalWarning.Bouton2action.

I don't know how to inject "string action" in ng-click 
I'm sure this is basic but I can't find the way I have to take.

Comment: try with `ng-click="modalWarning.Bouton1Action"`

Comment: try to assign the function directly to the btn:  `$scope.modalWarning.Button2Action = CloseCurrentMAJOK;` , then in the html `ng-click="modalWarning.Button2Action()"`?

Comment: None of the solutions work :-(.

Comment: i have tried : 
ng-click={{modalWarning.Bouton2Action}}
When i inspect Html i have the good code :
ng-click="CloseCurrentMAJOK()" 
but function is not called